# Cloudflare Worker CORS blocks POST requests even though 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'

Tags: cors, cloudflare-workers

I am a new user to Cloudflare workers, and can't figure out why CORS blocks my POST requests. The headers I send back in every Response are:

```js
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
```

However, when I start up my dev server (localhost:8787), it blocks the POST but not GET requests.

```js
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8787/api/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Workers-specific issue. Your server (e.g. your Worker code) needs to answer preflight requests, also known as an OPTIONS requests. The browser sends such a request before even sending the POST, and only allows the POST to proceed if the OPTIONS request says it is allowed.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: Since I have 'OPTIONS' listed as one of the allowed methods in my response headers, shouldn't it allow the POST to proceed, or am I understanding this wrong? Do I need to create a separate check in my server code to handle preflights?

Comment: You need to add code on the server side which handles OPTIONS requests. The OPTIONS request is sent before the POST request, in order to find out whether the POST request is allowed. If your server doesn't respond to the OPTIONS request with the necessary access control headers, then the browser will not send the POST request at all.